# Can i call some helper function with string name in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm struck with some problem.

Here is what i'm trying:

**can i achieve this:**

```
var case = 'toUpperCase()';

'abcd'.case;  //output ===>  ABCD
```

user will pass case `uppercase` or `lowercase`

```
function getIndex(obj){
    var index = window[String('someGlobalArray')].indexOf(String(obj.name).case);}
    var pass = {name:'helper',case:'toUpperCase'}; 
    someGlobalArray =  ['HELPER','A','b','C',.......]; 
    getIndex(pass);
```

Comment: Please be clearer about **what** you are trying to achieve, not how you tried to do it.

Comment: `var case = 'toUpperCase()'; 'abcd'.case;  //output ===>  ABCD` No, not possible like that. Though, if you were to use bracket notation instead, and called *outside* of the string, it could be

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Comment: How can this be node and Jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible, by using square bracket notation to access the function:

```js
const caseFunction = 'toUpperCase'

const result = 'abcd'[caseFunction]()

console.log(result)
```

---

You've edited the question since I answered, I'll see if I can make sense of what you're asking

Comment: This is ES6, yes?

Comment: @D_N the `const` part is, yes, these could be changed for `var`, though, if that was a problem